# React; parent taking input data from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, parent-child

I am making an app with React which takes user input from a drop down menu, makes an api call based on the value of the input and displays the results. The structure of the components is this.

```
Search
    Input
    Result
```

So, `Search` is the parent of the `Input` and `Result` components. I want to pass the values from `Input` to `Search`, where the call takes place. Then the result of the call is passed to `Result` (surprisingly enough).

I can hard code values in `Search` for the api call and the results display fine.

But I am having trouble figuring out how to pass the value of the input fields from `Input` to `Search`. I think I am supposed to access the child (Input) props from `Search`, but I don't see how to set them as you are not meant to have a component set it's own props.

I know this is wrong but what I have so far is:

```
let Input = React.createClass ({

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.genre = this.refs.genre.value;
    // or this.state.genre = this.refs.genre ? 
  },

  render() {
      return <div>
      <select ref="genre">
        <option value="28">Action</option>
        <option value="12">Adventure</option>
        <option value="16">Animation</option>
        <option value="35">Comedy</option>

        <option value="37">Western</option>
      </select>

      <select>
       <option ref="rating" type="text" placeholder="Rating"/>
      </select>

      <select>
       <option ref="type" type="text" placeholder="Type"/>
      </select>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
     </div>
    }
});

export default Input;
```

and `Search`

```
let Search = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      movies: ['Men In Black']
    };
  },

  componentDidMount(){

    let genre = this.props.genre || '';
    let url   = `http://theapi.org/3/discover/movie?${key}&with_genres=${genre}`;
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
      console.log('response.body.results', response.body.results)
      this.setState({
        movies: response.body.results.map(function(movie){
          return movie.title
        })
      });
    });
   },

  render(){
      console.log(this.state.movies)
      return (
        <div>
          <Input/>
          <ul>
            {this.state.movies.map( function(movie){
              return <Results key={movie.id} data={movie}/>;
            })}
          </ul>
         </div>
      );
   }
 });

 export default Search;
```

I hope you can see what I am trying to do here. It doesn't feel like it's that difficult, but my grasp of React's props and state is basic and even after reading the docs I need some explanation.

I guess my question is, am I supposed to assign data to a child's prop or state, and how do I access it from the parent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to parent component in react](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635897/passing-data-to-parent-component-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

Just remember this when you create a child component like Input, does it need keep track of states within the component? If not, you don't need to call componentDidMount in the child component. Just pass it up the value to the parent inside the child component like following

```
let Input = React.createClass ({

selectHandler(){ this.props.cb(value) } 

render() {
  return <div>
  <select onClick ={this.selectHandler.bind(this)} ref="genre">
    <option value="28">Action</option>
    <option value="12">Adventure</option>
    <option value="16">Animation</option>
    <option value="35">Comedy</option>

    <option value="37">Western</option>
  </select> ........
```

Comment: Hey thanks @slopeofhope, but how does the number from the value attribute get from the select option into the callback function (inside selectHandler)? At the moment I get an error saying value is undefined and if I hard code in a value the error says `cb` is not a function.

Comment: So then follow the rest of example from  brett thom. Also to retrieve the value you can do { this.props.cb( this.refs.genre.value)}

Comment: Great thanks @slopeofhope using `this.refs.genre.value` worked. Now I am successfully passing the information I need to the parent component. However, one thing I did differently was add a `button` element and put the `onClick` with `{this.selectHandler}` (without the `.bind(this)`) in there. So I can have multiple `<select>` values passed as arguments to the `selectHandler` on the click of the button. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flux approach with this like https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs or https://github.com/reactjs/redux as the best approach. Another way, even though uglier is to pass functions as props.

For instance add something like this to search

```
callBackExample(value) {
    this.setState({value: value});
},

render() {
    ...
    <Input cb = {this.callBackExample.bind(this} />
    ...
}
```

Then input can use this

```
this.props.cb(value)
```

To pass values back

Answer (score 0):

This method works:

1. Create a method in parent.That method must change the state of
   parent.
2. Pass that method to child as props. Pass child state to that
       method.
3. When the method will be called, it will accept child state
       as argument but will change the state of parent.

   i.e Child state
   gets send to parent state.

Live Demo: https://zly8w2xp33.codesandbox.io/