# How to get a value form a child component to a parent component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem that I want to get value from a child component and use it in the parent component.

This is the parent component and I'm passing a value I to its child through props and I want to get it back, so how can I achieve this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Rectangle from './Rectangle.js';

import '../App.css';

class Rect extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      rects:[],
      img_offset: [],
      rectStyle: []
    };
    this.unselectOtherRects = this.unselectOtherRects.bind(this);
    this.getFirstState = this.getFirstState.bind(this);
  }

  unselectOtherRects(e, i){
    alert(i)
    this.getFirstState();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getFirstState();
  }

  getFirstState(){
    const img = this.refs.img;
    var x  = img.offsetLeft;
    var y = img.offsetTop;
    this.setState({img_offset:[x, y]});

    var rects = this.props.rects;

    var rectangles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
      rectangles[i] = {
        border: '1px solid white',
        position : 'absolute',
        width : rects[i][0] + 'px',
        height : rects[i][1] + 'px',
        left : x + rects[i][2] + 'px',
        top : y + rects[i][3] + 'px'
      };
    }

    this.setState({rectStyle:rectangles});
    alert("Hiii")
    var test = this.state.rectStyle;
    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
      alert(test[i].border)
    }
  }

  render() {
    let Rectangles;
    var targetRects = this.state.rectStyle;


    if (targetRects.length > 0) {
        Rectangles=(
          <div>
          {targetRects.map(function(rect, index){
            return (
              <Rectangle  key={index} i={index} initialState={this.unselectOtherRects.bind(this, i)} coords={this.state.rectStyle[index]}></Rectangle>
            )
          }.bind(this))}
          </div>
        )
    }
    else{
      Rectangles=(<div></div>)
    }

    return (
      <div>
      <form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <Row id="image_preview" className="row">
          <span id="photo">
            <img ref="img" id="img" src={this.props.path} />
            {Rectangles}
          </span>
        </Row>
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Rect;
```

I tried to get the index directly on clicking the component but it did not work and the result is undefined.

And here is the child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {Row} from 'react-bootstrap';

import '../App.css';

class Rectangle extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      coords:this.props.coords
    }
    this.onRectClick = this.onRectClick.bind(this);
  }

  onRectClick(e){

    this.props.initialState();
    // var rect_style = this.state.coords;
    // rect_style.border = '1px solid black';
    // this.setState({coords:rect_style});

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onRectClick} style={this.state.coords}></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Rectangle;
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want, can you please clarify whether you mean?
some value updated in your child component, that value should be available in parent component or something else?

Comment: I just want to use the index value from here
<Rectangle  key={index} i={index} initialState={this.unselectOtherRects.bind(this, i)} coords={this.state.rectStyle[index]}></Rectangle>
in the Rect component
when clicking on a single Rectangle Component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to parent component in react](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635897/passing-data-to-parent-component-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the value in parent component as a state, for example:

this.state = {
    valueControlledByChild: null
  };

To enable the child component be able to change this state variable, you can create this function in parent component and pass it down to the child component:

```
setParentState(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    this.setState({
      [key]: obj[key]
    });
  });
};

render() {
  ...
  <ChildComponent setParentState={this.setStateParentState} />
}
```

Please don't forget to add this in your parent component constructor:

```
this.setParentState = this.setParentState.bind(this);
```

Now in your child component, you can call this method easily to override its value by:

```
this.props.setParentState({
  valueControlledByChild: NEW_VALUE
});
```

And in your parent component you can refer to this.state.valueControlledByChild to get its updated value.