# how to get the value in Parent component using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and i wanted to get `range` value from child component(salary.js) to parent component(App.js). i couldn't able to find out how to pass the props to App component. My objective is get the range value which is stored in `salary.js` to App.js in `price` in order to post the value.

Can anyone please help me in this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe a callback to parent component work for you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635897/passing-data-to-parent-component-in-react). If child component is more than one level deep it would be better to use the React context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 1):

U can use callback function.

```
PaterentComponent  {

  const myCallbackFunction = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  }

  return (
    <ChildComponent callback={myCallbackFunction}> </ ChildComponent>
  )
}

ChildComponent {

/// dothmth

   return <button  onClick{props.myCallbackFuntion("I'mcallback")}>CallbackFunciton</button>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass props from a component to its parent. You need to store the rangeValue inside your App component. It's called "lifting state up". Your App component should pass the rangeValue and a callback to modify it to Salary. Salary will then display the value it received from props and call the callback whenever the value needs to be updated